# How high is the spacing between UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview

Anybody know how big is the spacing between `UITableViewCell`s in points ? That is I would like to know whether there are any screen spaces allocated between cells in an `UITableView` and how high are they, in each of these separator styles:

- `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` – is it 0pt ?
- `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine` – is it 1pt?
- `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched` – is it 1pt or 2pt?

The problem I'm currently facing is that I have a variable-height cells and I need to calculate how high a group of cells may be. Currently I'm using `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine` separator style and assuming that the inter-cell spacing is 1pt high but my calculations are often off.

That is, supposed that there are three cells, each 40 pt high, my assumption is that the total height will be `40 + 1 + 40 + 1 + 40 = 122` points high.

Questions are:

- Is it true that a single line separator takes 1pt height between the cells?
- If not, what is the height of the separator line, if any space is allocated at all (i.e. doesn't "eat" into the adjacent cell's space.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem you can solve very easily by taking a screenshot from interface builder and then measuring it in Photoshop, however I've saved you the trouble:

The separator is not added to the the height of the table cell - it is drawn in front of the cell, so if your table cell height is 44 (the default) then the combined height of two cells will be 88, regardless of which separator style you choose.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't thought of taking a measurement of IB or mock application with default table view cells.